# Customising the default TFS Git build template

Tags: git, tfsbuild

I've saved the default TFS Git build template (`GitTemplate.12.xaml`) to a new Class Library project, fixed all the missing references and when I compile I get this:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Xaml.targets(347,5): 
error XC1043: Extension 'Microsoft.Activities.Build.Validation.ValidationBuildExtension' 
threw an exception of type 'System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriterException' 
  'The invocation of the constructor on type 
  'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Activities.Git.GitPull' that matches 
  the specified binding constraints threw an exception.'.`
```

Any help as to what could be wrong?

Comment: You don't need to compile a build workflow, it often fails. If the workflow in the designer doesn't show any errors I tend to just try it on the server. Usually it works.

Comment: Was following these instructions http://tfsbuildextensions.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=How%20to%20integrate%20the%20extensions%20into%20a%20build%20template&referringTitle=Documentation Attempting to swap out the MSBuild task and replace it with a call to VS2008 devenv

Comment: Did you set the BuildAction to `None` for the build.xaml file?

Comment: It's set to `XamlAppDef`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You missed a step on the tutorial you've been following. After adding the `GitTemplate.12.xaml` you should set the BuildAction to None:

> 3 .  On the added file set the build action property to none

That will allow you to edit the build workflow without having to compile it. The workflow just won't compile, that doesn't mean it won't run. Don't ask me why that is, I asked the Visual Studio Product Team some time back and they confirmed that the build workflow isn't supposed to compile.